# How to get excel VBA to find a name then click the hyperlink

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

This is the piece I am stuck on, everything else is working.

```
Sub Avidie()
Dim i As Long
Dim url As String
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Set links = .document.getelementbyclass("invoice-number-hyperlink").getelementsbyname("25407")(0).Click
```

I am up to the point where I have the Webpage code, which is below, and I want my code to find the link that has that class and name, and click it. How can I fix this?? The class name is the same on multiple parts of this page, but the name Is what I’m looking up so I need to find it by that.

```
<a class="invoice-number-hyperlink" onclick="avid.navigateHelper['PAQ-Invoice'](this);" href="#/invoices/70c2373a-ac71-43f2-a9e0-8d0332f1a19b?fromQueue=true">25407</a>
```

Comment: Try `getElementsByClassName("invoice-number-hyperlink")(0).click`

Comment: So there are multiple links with that class name. I NEED to do it using the name.

Comment: The `a` tag you have listed doesn't have a `name` property, the value `25407` is likely the  innerText of the anchor. You can loop over element with a class of `invoice-number-hyperlink` and check the value of the innerText property.

Comment: Is the string `PAQ-Invoice` unique to the link you want to click? What parts of the html shown are unique to the link to click? Is the link always at a specific position e.g. 2nd link within a parent tag?

Comment: @RyanWildry sorry im SO new to VBA idk what the a tag is that youre referring to, BUT 25407 IS the innertext... can you please let me know which things youre saying I should change?

Comment: @QHarr, everything is either the same for each button (which corresponds to invoices), or completely random. My excel file has the download invoice of invoice #25407 within it, so thats what im going to use eventually to auto-download each one.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the part of the code you provided, as well as the methods that other members of the community have mentioned, you can traverse all eligible s according to the class, filter according to the text content, and then select and click. I have created a simple example, I hope it can be helpful to you:

```
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://www.example.com/"
With appIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("invoice-number-hyperlink")(0).Click

For Each link In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("invoice-number-hyperlink")
    If link.Text = "25407" Then
        link.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

And page:

```
<a class="invoice-number-hyperlink" onclick="window.alert('jump to google...')" href="https://www.google.com/">25407</a>
```